# Laravel add children to a model

Tags: php, laravel

I am starting out with Laravel and get how most of the basics work but not sure how to add children to a model or collection. So basically I have lets say 3 models (Users, Distributors and Accounts). Accounts belong to Distributors, and Distributors belong to Users. Both are "One To Many" relationships so a Distributor can have many Accounts and A User can have many Distributors.

This is in my controller that gets the Distributors for that user

```
$distributors   = User::find($id)->distributors;
```

My User Model

```
public function distributors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Distributor');
    }
```

My Distributor Model

```
public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Account');
    }
```

What I would love is to have the accounts appended as children to the Distributor model. Right now if I `dd($distributors);` I get all the Distributors for that User, but no Accounts for each of the Distributors.

Can I add some function so I can add them to the Distributors? Like using this call:

```
 $distributors   = User::find($id)->distributors->with('accounts');
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. What I had to do was add the "with" to the User Model not in the controller so:

```
public function distributors()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Distributor')->with('Accounts');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can add an `Account` to a `Distributor`, **for example**, like this:

```
Distributor::find(1)->accounts()->save($account);
```

In your case, you can add an `Account` to a `Distributor` like this:

```
$distributors = User::with('distributors')->find($id)->distributors;
//A User can have many Distributors so you need to select one distributor,
//the first one in this example with index 0 !
$distributors[0]->accounts()->save($account);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you explain this? How is this getting and saving the accounts to the distributers pulled in the query? It looks like you are just passing an id of 1?

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying. I just figured there was a way to add this to the actual model every time a get a list of distributers I can also get all the accounts associated with them not just one at a time. The main goal is to return a list of all the users accounts. These are associated to them through the distributer.